# Display divs in the row on small screens

Tags: javascript, css

I am trying to display these divs with flex. But when the width of the screen gets less then approximately 500px I see only one div on the row. How to keep 2 divs on the row when the width of the screen gets less than it was before?

```
.box {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap; 
  align-content: space-between;
}
.wrapper {
  margin: 20px;
  background: beige;
  border-radius: 15px;
}
.divla{
  margin: 15px;
}
@media(max-width:500px) {   
.box{      
  width: 50%;
}

 <div class="box">
   <div class="wrapper">
     <div class="divla">
        <h2 style="text-align:center; margin-top: 3px">hello</h2> 
     </div>
   </div>
   <div class="wrapper">
     <div class="divla">
        <h2 style="text-align:center; margin-top: 3px">hello</h2> 
     </div>
   </div>
   <div class="wrapper">
     <div class="divla">
        <h2 style="text-align:center; margin-top: 3px">hello</h2> 
    </div>
   </div>
</div> `
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please use nowrap instead of wrap in flex-wrap property.

```
.box {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap; 
  align-content: space-between;
}
```

You can also remove flex-wrap: nowrap; from the class as nowrap is set by default.

```
.box {
  display: flex;
  align-content: space-between;
}
```

Comment: On the first glance it works well but on some smaller screen it made the third div dissapear or I see just a half of it.

Comment: Is this what you are looking for https://jsfiddle.net/kawal/r1Lxfwho/3/

Comment: The third div should move to the next row, below the first two divs.

Comment: Please check this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/kawal/r1Lxfwho/34/. You need to wrap the items and add css to third item using nth-child.

Comment: Thank you! You could give it as an answer!